# SqlAlchemy: query to count non existing items

Tags: sqlalchemy

To count notifications that wasn't read by a user, I use the following code:

```py
query = query.filter(
    or_(Notifs.tid == current_user.id, # is targeted to the user
        Notifs.target_groups.any(Role.id.in_([r.id for r in current_user.roles])))) # user is among the target groups of the notification

count = 0
for notif in query.all():
    q1 = UserReads.query.filter_by(uid = current_user.id, nid = notif.id).first()
    if not q1 or not q1.read:
         count += 1
```

Could it be done in a single query and then using `query.count()`?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your schema.  Does Notification also have a relationship to user or does every Notification automatically apply to all users ?

Comment: I modified the answer to show my query to get user's notifications. No, every user has its own ones. I get them via the code above, you can give opinion over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Option 2" below I think is the most clear and I think the list of "read" notifications will be shorter than unread because it will be filtered explicitly by the user.  I haven't found great docs on using "any_".

This should work for SQLAlchemy 2.0.

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    DateTime,
    Boolean,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint,
    Table,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func, and_, or_, not_
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased, relationship


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


class Notification(Base):
    __tablename__ = "notifications"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    target_roles = relationship("Role", back_populates='notifications', secondary='notifications_roles')
    user_reads = relationship("UserRead", back_populates='notification')
    target_user = relationship("User")


class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = relationship("User", secondary="users_roles", back_populates="roles")
    notifications = relationship("Notification", back_populates='target_roles', secondary='notifications_roles')

notifications_roles = Table('notifications_roles', Base.metadata,
                            Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                            Column("role_id", Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'), nullable=False),
                            Column("notification_id", Integer, ForeignKey('notifications.id'), nullable=False),
                            UniqueConstraint("notification_id", "role_id", name="notification_role_uc"))


users_roles_t = Table("users_roles", Base.metadata,
                      Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                      Column("user_id", ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False),
                      Column("role_id", ForeignKey('roles.id'), nullable=False),
                      UniqueConstraint("user_id", "role_id", name="user_role_uc"),
)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    roles = relationship("Role", secondary="users_roles", back_populates="users")
    user_reads = relationship("UserRead", back_populates='user')


class UserRead(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_reads'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    nid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('notifications.id'), nullable=False)
    read = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('uid', 'nid'),
    )
    user = relationship(User, back_populates='user_reads')
    notification = relationship(Notification, back_populates='user_reads')


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    """
    Set up 3 notification to demonstrate different unread/read states.
    """
    u1 = User()
    session.add(u1)
    session.flush()

    r1 = Role()
    r2 = Role()
    session.add_all([r1, r2])
    session.flush()

    u1.roles.append(r1)
    session.flush()

    # Notifications target user.
    n1, n2, n3 = Notification(), Notification(), Notification()
    session.add_all([n1, n2, n3])
    n1.tid = n2.tid = n3.tid = u1.id
    session.flush()

    #First case: User read exists and it is False. (should count)
    ur1 = UserRead(read=False)
    session.add(ur1)
    ur1.notification = n1
    ur1.user = u1

    #Second case: User read exists but it is True (should not count)
    ur2 = UserRead(read=True)
    session.add(ur2)
    ur2.notification = n2
    ur2.user = u1
    session.flush()
    session.commit()

    #Third case: User read does not exist (should count)
    #...

with Session(engine) as session:
    """
    Setup 4 cases, the first 3 are similar to the above cases but notification is targeted at user's role instead of user.
    The last case does not target the user at all so should not be counted as unread even though no UserRead exists.
    """

    u1 = session.query(User).first()
    r1 = u1.roles[0]
    r2 = session.query(Role).where(Role.id != r1.id).first()
    n1, n2, n3, n4 = Notification(), Notification(), Notification(), Notification()
    session.add_all([n1, n2, n3, n4])
    # Target u1's role.
    n1.target_roles.append(r1)
    n2.target_roles.append(r1)
    n3.target_roles.append(r1)
    # Does not target u1's role.
    n4.target_roles.append(r2)
    session.flush()

    #First case: UserRead exists and it is False. (should count)
    ur1 = UserRead(read=False)
    session.add(ur1)
    ur1.notification = n1
    ur1.user = u1

    #Second case: UserRead exists but it is True (should not count)
    ur2 = UserRead(read=True)
    session.add(ur2)
    ur2.notification = n2
    ur2.user = u1
    session.flush()
    session.commit()

    #Third case: UserRead does not exist (should count)
    #...


    #Fourth case: User's role is not targeted (should not count)
    #...



with Session(engine) as session:
    current_user = session.query(User).first()

    #
    # Option 1, using unread subquery.
    #
    target_subq = select(Notification.id).outerjoin(
        Notification.target_roles
    ).where(
        or_(
            Notification.tid == current_user.id,
            Role.id.in_([r.id for r in current_user.roles])))
    # Decide which notifications have not been read by this user.
    unread_subq = select(Notification.id).outerjoin(
        UserRead, and_(
            Notification.id == UserRead.nid,
            UserRead.uid == current_user.id
    )).where(or_(
        # We recorded current user didn't read it.
        UserRead.read == False,
        # There is no UserRead record at all for current user.
        UserRead.id == None))
    target_unread_q = select(
        func.count(Notification.id)
    ).where(
        Notification.id.in_(unread_subq),
        Notification.id.in_(target_subq))
    print (session.execute(target_unread_q).scalar())


    #
    # Option 2, using negation of read subquery.
    #
    read_subq = select(Notification.id).join(
        UserRead, and_(
            Notification.id == UserRead.nid,
            UserRead.uid == current_user.id
    )).where(
        UserRead.read == True)
    target_unread_q = select(
        func.count(Notification.id)
    ).where(
        # It has not been read.
        Notification.id.not_in(read_subq),
        # It matches the target.
        Notification.id.in_(target_subq))
    print (session.execute(target_unread_q).scalar())
```

The query format string (taken from log output of `echo = True`) for option 2.

```py
"""SELECT count(notifications.id) AS count_1 
FROM notifications 
WHERE (notifications.id NOT IN (SELECT notifications.id 
FROM notifications JOIN user_reads ON notifications.id = user_reads.nid AND user_reads.uid = %(uid_1)s 
WHERE user_reads.read = true)) AND notifications.id IN (SELECT notifications.id 
FROM notifications LEFT OUTER JOIN (notifications_roles AS notifications_roles_1 JOIN roles ON roles.id = notifications_roles_1.role_id) ON notifications.id = notifications_roles_1.notification_id 
WHERE notifications.tid = %(tid_1)s OR roles.id IN (%(id_1_1)s))"""
```

The substitutions for the query:

```py
{'uid_1': 1, 'tid_1': 1, 'id_1_1': 1}
```

This should return `4` matching "unread" notifications.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer. By the way, do you think my own approach is correct and equivalent?

Comment: I'm not sure if the use of `any()` would work correctly.  The combined query in my answer would be one query (in addition to getting the current user and getting the current user's roles).

Comment: I tested this on postgresql, I am not sure about how well other dbs handle subqueries like this.

Comment: Thank you very much again. You mean your combined query works but my separate one with `any` may not? And I'd better to use your solution?

Comment: Is there a direct relationship between `Notifs.target_groups` and `Role.id`?

Comment: yes similar to what you wrote `target_groups = relationship('Role', secondary='target_groups',
                            backref='notifs')
`

Comment: `targt_groups = db.Table(
    'target_groups',
    db.Column('notifs_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Notifs.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)   
`

Comment: When I change my tables to your models, I get `KeyError: 'notif'` on submitting a form to insert a notification. `notif`  is the same  `notification` on `NotificationGroup`. Strange error! as it doesn't recognize the relationship!!

Comment: In my form I had a relationship to Role filled by Roles, now maybe the error is because of that. However if I fill it with NotificationGroup, I don't know how get roles to fill the combo box ( I use flask-admin forms)

Comment: I rolled back `target_groups` relation to use NotificationGroups (in my case TargetGroups) as `secondary` table. This resolved the problem of form filling and submission. Also, it seems your query still work for them using `target_groups` as joining bridge. I brought it in the next comment

Comment: SELECT count(`Notifs`.id) AS unreads 
FROM `Notifs` 
WHERE `Notifs`.id IN (SELECT `Notifs`.id 
FROM `Notifs` LEFT OUTER JOIN `UserReads` ON `Notifs`.id = `UserReads`.nid AND `UserReads`.uid = %s 
WHERE `UserReads`.`read` = false OR `UserReads`.id IS NULL) AND `Notifs`.id IN (SELECT `Notifs`.id 
FROM `TargetGroups`, `Notifs` LEFT OUTER JOIN (`TargetGroups` AS `TargetGroups_1` INNER JOIN `role` ON `role`.id = `TargetGroups_1`.role_id) ON `Notifs`.id = `TargetGroups_1`.nid 
WHERE `Notifs`.uid = %s OR `TargetGroups`.role_id IN ([POSTCOMPILE_role_id_1]))

Comment: @Ahmad I think having a secondary table is better than what I had but I wasn't sure what the relationship was.  I updated the code.  I added another option that uses `not_in` and a subquery for read notifications that I think is better than the direct subquery for unread notifications.  The overall query and sub queries I think are simpler than `any_`.

Comment: I agree! Thank you overall.